# How to get position of listitem using setonitemclicklistener and send to next activity

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

In my app I am getting response from server and displayint it in listview, now what I am trying is when user click on listitem it should get position of it and need to send it to next activity, but it is not working.

Following is mt snippet code

```
btn_go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(
                        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
                        || connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(
                                ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                // listView1.removeAllViews();
                listView1.setAdapter(null);
                arraylist_oper = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                // listView1.notify();
                new getOperationalControlList().execute();  
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //qr =  ((String) listView1.getItemAtPosition(position)).toString();

            Intent intent=new Intent(OperationalControl.this,DispatchTracking.class);
            intent.putExtra("arrow_val", "2");
            intent.putExtra("qrcodes", qr);
            Toast.makeText(OperationalControl.this, qr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

class getOperationalControlList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private String msg = "";
    int register_error = 1;

    JSONArray operation;
    JSONObject obc;
    String error;
    String access_token, office_name, office_id;
    String user_id;
    String name;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(OperationalControl.this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.show();
        noresponse.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        JSONObject jsonObjSend;
        String content = null;
        arraylist_oper = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try {

            consts.pref = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
            consts.editor = consts.pref.edit();
            String OperationalControlList_URL = ((consts.pref
                    .getString(consts.Base_URL,
                            consts.Base_URL)) + consts.OperationalControlList_URL);
            Log.d("OperationalControlList_URL url:",
                    OperationalControlList_URL);

            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(OperationalControlList_URL);

            System.out.println("URL :-"
                    + consts.OperationalControlList_URL.toString());

            user_id = consts.pref.getString("user_id", "");
            access_token = consts.pref.getString("access_token", "");
            office_id = consts.pref.getString("office_id", "");
            date = date_dropdown.getText().toString();

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    5);

            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", user_id));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token",
                    access_token));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("filter", filter));
            nameValuePair
                    .add(new BasicNameValuePair("office_id", office_id));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", date));

            // Encoding POST data
            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                System.out.println("USER_ID : " + user_id.toString());
                System.out.println("access_token : "
                        + access_token.toString());
                System.out.println("filter : " + filter.toString());
                System.out.println("office_id : " + office_id.toString());
                System.out.println("date : " + date.toString());

                content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                Log.d("aaa", content);

                jsonObjSend = new JSONObject(content.toString());

                if (jsonObjSend.getString("status").equals("2")) {

                    register_error = 1;
                    error = jsonObjSend.getString("error");
                    if (error.equals("3")) {
                        msg = jsonObjSend.getString("message");
                    } else if (error.equals("4")) {
                        msg = jsonObjSend.getString("message");
                    } else if (error.equals("5")) {
                        msg = jsonObjSend.getString("message");
                    } else if (error.equals("6")) {
                        msg = jsonObjSend.getString("message");
                    } else if (error.equals("7")) {
                        msg = jsonObjSend.getString("message");
                    } else if (error.equals("8")) {
                        msg = jsonObjSend.getString("message");
                    } else if (error.equals("9")) {
                        msg = jsonObjSend.getString("message");
                    } else if (error.equals("10")) {
                        msg = jsonObjSend.getString("message");
                    } else if (error.equals("11")) {
                        msg = jsonObjSend.getString("message");
                    } else if (error.equals("12")) {
                        msg = jsonObjSend.getString("message");
                    } else {
                        msg = jsonObjSend.getString("message");
                    }
                    // {"status":1,"message":"There is no activity of the selected day and filtering otpions"}
                } else if (jsonObjSend.getString("status").equals("1")) {

                    if (jsonObjSend.has("message"))
                        msg = jsonObjSend.getString("message");
                    // msg = jsonObjSend.getString("message");
                    register_error = 0;
                    operation = new JSONArray();
                    if (jsonObjSend.has("list")) {
                        operation = jsonObjSend.getJSONArray("list");

                        // arraylist_oper = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,
                        // String>>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < operation.length(); i++) {
                            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            qr = operation.getJSONObject(i)
                                    .getString("qrcode");
                            type = operation.getJSONObject(i)
                                    .getString("type").toString();

                            Log.d("Types", type);
                            String origin = operation.getJSONObject(i)
                                    .getString("origin");
                            String destiny = operation.getJSONObject(i)
                                    .getString("destiny");
                            String stop_status = operation.getJSONObject(i)
                                    .getString("stop_status");
                            String stop_status_name = operation
                                    .getJSONObject(i).getString(
                                            "stop_status_name");
                            String stop_status_color = operation
                                    .getJSONObject(i).getString(
                                            "stop_status_color");
                            map.put("qrcode", qr);
                            map.put("type", type);
                            map.put("origin", origin);
                            map.put("destiny", destiny);
                            map.put("stop_status", stop_status);
                            map.put("stop_status_name", stop_status_name);
                            map.put("stop_status_color", stop_status_color);
                            // map.put("status_name", status_name);
                            arraylist_oper.add(map);

                            Log.d("qrcode:", qr + " type: " + type
                                    + " origine: " + origin);
                        }
                    } else {

                        msg = jsonObjSend.getString("message");
                    }

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        if (error.equals("6")) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(OperationalControl.this,LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            OperationalControl.this.finish();

        }
        try {
            if (arraylist_oper.size() > 0) {
                Operational_LazyAdapter adpt = new Operational_LazyAdapter(
                        getApplicationContext(), arraylist_oper);
                listView1.setAdapter(adpt);
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg,
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Office não definir corretamente ou" + msg,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                noresponse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Response

```
{"status":1,
    "list":[{
        "qrcode":"#00000757-00000277-700101-0000000040",
        "type":"Tipo de Opera\u00e7\u00e3o: Chegada",
        "origin":"Origem: ARMAMAR (757)",
        "destiny":"Destino: REGUA (277)",
        "stop_status":6,
        "stop_status_name":"Finalizado",
        "stop_status_color":"#cccccc"
    },
    {
        "qrcode":"#00000278-00000277-700101-0000000041",
        "type":"Tipo de Opera\u00e7\u00e3o: Chegada",
        "origin":"Origem: LAMEGO (278)",
        "destiny":"Destino: REGUA (277)",
        "stop_status":6,
        "stop_status_name":"Finalizado",
        "stop_status_color":"#cccccc"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Do you want all JSON Data to next Activity?

Comment: Then  either pass json object to in bundle or pass your final arraylist to next Activity. Check my answer.

Comment: @PiyushGupta need your help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951608/java-lang-classcastexception-android-view-viewgrouplayoutparams-cannot-be-cast/30951695#30951695

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just you need to pass your `HashMap` `Arraylist` to next `Activity`. Like,

```
intent.putExtra("myList",arraylist_oper);
```

and in your next `Activity` just retrieve as

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> mylist = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>)intent.getSerializableExtra("myList");
```

#### EDIT :

You need to pass your `qrCode` too next Activity

```
intent.putExtra("qrcodes", arraylist_oper.get(position).get("qrcode")));
```

Now retrieve in next activity as

```
String qrCode = intent.getStringExtra("qrcodes");
```

Now check your retrivable arraylist in your second activity using For loop.

```
for(int i=0; i < myList.size ; i++) {

  if(qrCode.equals(myList.get(i).get("qrcode"))){
      // get your data here you can get according to qrCode. Like

      String density = myList.get(i).get("destiny"); // same for others

  }
```

Comment: in my next activity i am getting both record..i want perticuler record..i mean if click on records with qrcode #00000757-00000277-700101-0000000040..thenin next activity i want only record with #00000757-00000277-700101-0000000040..got it ??

Comment: then you need to pass qrcode to next activity like  intent.putExtra("qrcode", arraylist_oper.get(position).get("qrcode")); Then in next activity after retriving it just check if(qrcode.equals("#00000757-00000277-700101-0000000040")) { then show only that data.

Comment: ok but what if i need to send the other records like type,destiny etc etc.which is with qrcode  #00000757-00000277-700101-0000000040.. as mentioned in response..

Answer (score 1):

On the Intent you create on the list item click listener you should add all variables you need.

In your case add

```
intent.putExtra("position", position);
```

In your DispatchTracking Activity use

```
int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");
```